# Выгрузка файла на сервер POST способом?

Tags: python, linux, post

Нужно отправить .txt файл на сервер, как это можно реализовать?.

Comment: [requests.post](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 4):

Отправка файла через [requests.post](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) (`Multipart-encoded`):

```
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

---

Теперь [подробнее](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d51131f9cf1d76c0dc5e3228677767ff9abee036/requests__examples/post_file.py).

Для тестирования будем отправлять текущий файл скрипта в https://httpbin.org/post

```
import requests

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
abs_file_name = __file__
```

Самый простой пример отправки:

```
files = {'file': open(abs_file_name, 'rb')}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(rs)
print(rs.text)
```

С ручным указанием имени файла:

```
files = {'file': ('my_file.py', open(abs_file_name, 'rb'))}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(rs)
print(rs.text)
```

Отправка строки как файл. Удобно, что не нужно предварительно данные в файл писать:

```
files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(rs)
print(rs.text)
```

Можно и байтами отправить:

```
files = {'file': ('report.csv', b'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
rs = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(rs)
print(rs.text)
```